# DLL and drawing function disappearing

Tags: c++

main.cpp (dll) http://pastebin.com/Z811YSz7
Funkcje.h http://pastebin.com/siZrUBh0
When i injected this dll to a game then i dont see letters.
When i maked drawing function in a while(1) then the letters are appearing and disappearing.
How to make the drawing function to be on the top of this game all the time.

```
    #include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Funkcje.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
    DWORD fdwreason,
    LPVOID lpReversed)
{
    switch (fdwreason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < getToplevelWindows().size(); i++){
                hdc = GetDC(getToplevelWindows()[i]);
                TextOut(hdc, 150, 150, L"TEST", 4);
                ReleaseDC(getToplevelWindows()[i], hdc);
        }
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: `DllMain` is only called once.

Comment: But when i took from "for" to hdc);} a while(1), then drawing function was called not only once.

Comment: Yeah but now its simply calling as many times as it can, consuming all the CPU available.

Comment: Havenard Yeah, it is calling as many times as it can and it is appearing and disappearing. I want to get on the top this string, that it won't disappearing.

Comment: Then read my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DllMain` is only called once, when the DLL is loaded. This is not where you should be putting your code.

In order to properly "inject" code into a process (via DLL or any other mean) you must first determine what function or event in that process you want to **hook**.

In this case, I suppose you want to hook the window event `WM_PAINT`, a callback from the system sent to the window's procedure telling it that it should repaint its content for whatever reason. (This may not be always correct though, because a program can use other methods of updating a window content.)

So what you are going to do is find the window handle you want to hook, and replace its callback procedure with your own:

```
WNDPROC originalProc = SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)myHookProc);
```

But of course, not before having `myHookProc` defined and doing its job of hooking `WM_PAINT`:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK myHookProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT originalResult = originalProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); // call original first
    if (uMsg == WM_PAINT)
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        TextOut(hdc, 150, 150, L"TEST", 4);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    }
    return originalResult;
}
```

If you are dealing with multiple windows, you may want to use a `std::unordered_map<HWND, WNDPROC>` to keep relation between each window handle and its original procedure.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3tgyn9Q0 And the error C2664: 'LONG SetWindowLongW(HWND,int,LONG)' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'LRESULT (__stdcall *)(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'LONG' What i'm doing wrong and Thanks for helping ;)

Comment: Try with `(LONG_PTR)myHookProc`.

Comment: If i try (LONG_PTR)myHookProc then i got this error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'LONG' to 'WNDPROC'